# Getting the height multiple elements aplying to siblings

Tags: jquery

I have this problem I dont know what im missing so far I have this code
I have a dropdown menu that inside has 1 big column and other 4 divs next to them, I have to make the other divs the same height of the first div.. I wrote this

```
$('.dropdown div:first-child').each(function(){
$this = $(this)
var $height = $this.height()
$(".dropdown div:first-child").siblings("div").css("height", $height)
});
```

the problem is that the variable $height is returning a 0 value.. do you know why Im not getting each height?

Thank you in advance

//edit

http://jsfiddle.net/DsBF2/

so you can have an Idea...

Comment: Probbaly just a code paste typo but your line endings are missing semicolons. Oh and add units to your css height statement or just use .height().

Comment: well, when I alert ($height = $this.height()); it returns 0... so thats my biggest problem now hehe :P

Comment: setup an example http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You select a single element with the `:first-child` selector and then you try to loop that single element with `.each()`?

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson OP is looping through the class of .dropdown

Comment: I have multiples divs with the class "dropdown" i select the first child of each.. Im setting the jsfiddle so It will be more clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DsBF2/1/

```
$('.dropdown div').each(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var $height = $this.height();
    $this.siblings("div").css("height", $height);
});
```

**UPDATE**

This code would be better as the above goes through every child div unnecessarily

```
$('.dropdown').each(function(){    
    $this = $(this);
    var $div = $this.find("div:first-child");
    var $height = $div.height();
    $div.siblings("div").css("height", $height);
});
```

here http://jsfiddle.net/DsBF2/14/

Comment: thanks, it seems more than a display:none problem, :P thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this instead:

```
$('.dropdown div:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).siblings("div").height( $(this).height() );
});​
```

**[Updated jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DsBF2/6/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It should do what you ask for.

```
var height = 0;
$('.dropdown div:first-child').each(function(k,v) {
    height = 0;
    $(this).siblings("div").each(function(k2,v2) {
        if(height == 0) { 
            height = $(this).height(); 
        }                       
    }).css('height', height);
});
```

---

#### Update

If you really want a trimmed out version, this should do it

```
$('.dropdown div').each(function(){
    var height = $(this).height();
    $(this).siblings("div").css("height", height);
});
```

Comment: I want to put the height of the first-child on the siblings no the other way around .. for what I see in your code I get the height of the largest sibling isnt?

Comment: keeps styling it with "height: 0px" :S same as mine :(

Comment: there's no need for the second each function..wasted computation

Comment: @ChristianIsai, In the First snippet, I came from a wrong angle of making max height, but even so, it gives maximum control, however if not needed, it is in fact wasted computation. I updated a snippet with trimmed down version.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/DsBF2/12/)

```
$('.dropdown div').each(function() {
    var $height = $(this).height(); //get the height of the first one
    $(this).siblings('div').css("height", $height); //set the siblings css
    return; //no need to iterate over all divs since work is done
});
```